# Showing a message if specific times on specific days

Tags: php

I want to show a message on my site if it's after 5:00 PM on Thursday, and the whole day Friday.

I managed to get the code to work for Friday, but don't have any idea how to also get it to show on Thursday after 5.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$d=date("D");
if ($d=="Fri") 
{
echo 'Items may ship out after the weekend.';
}
```

How can I also get this to show on Thursday after 5:00?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to get the current hour?

Comment: `$h=date("h"); echo $h;` gives you the hour.. google this stuff.

Comment: $h=date("H"); should work, but I'm not sure how to combine that with the day, and making sure $h is greater than 17...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$d=date("D");
if ($d=="Fri" || ($d=="Thu" && date("Hi")>="1700")) {
   echo 'Items may ship out after the weekend.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Schreiber for your addition

Comment: Should work, wasn't sure how to combine everything properly...
Thanks a lot!